# How to enrich Scala collections with my own generic `map` (the right way)?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to enrich Scala collections with my own `map` method, and I'm close but the implicit conversion doesn't work.  Besides that, is there anything else I'm missing here?  I'm looking at various other resources on the Web, **including SO answers that this question is being marked as duplicating**, and many are missing something here and there (e.g. using `C[A] <: GenTraversable[A]`, using `b()` instead of `b(xs)`, forgetting about `Array`, forgetting about `BitSet`, etc.).

```
implicit def conv[A,C](xs: C)(implicit ev: C <:< GenTraversableLike[A,C]) = new {
  def mymap[B,D](f: A => B)(implicit b: CanBuildFrom[C,B,D]): D = b(xs).result // placeholder
}

scala> conv(List(1,2,3))
res39: java.lang.Object{def mymap[B,D](f: Int => B)(implicit b: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[Int],B,D]): D} = $$$$2c9d7a9074166de3bf8b66cf7c45a3ed$$$$anon$1@3ed0eea6

scala> conv(List(1,2,3))mymap(_+1)
res40: List[Int] = List()

scala> conv(BitSet(1,2,3))mymap(_+1)
res41: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet()

scala> conv(BitSet(1,2,3))mymap(_.toFloat)
res42: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Float] = Set()

scala> List(1,2,3)mymap(_+1)
<console>:168: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< scala.collection.IterableLike[A,List[Int]].
              List(1,2,3)mymap(_+1)
                  ^

scala> implicit def conv[A, C](xs: C)(implicit ev: C => GenTraversable[A]) = new {
     | def mymap[B,D](f: A => B)(implicit b: CanBuildFrom[GenTraversable[A],B,D]): D =
     | xs map f
     | }
conv: [A, C](xs: C)(implicit ev: C => scala.collection.GenTraversable[A])java.lang.Object{def mymap[B,D](f: A => B)(implicit b: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.GenTraversable[A],B,D]): D}

scala> conv(Array(1)) mymap (_+1)
res6: scala.collection.GenTraversable[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2)

scala> Array(1) mymap (_+1)
<console>:68: error: No implicit view available from Array[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversable[A].
              Array(1) mymap (_+1)
                   ^
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing my own generic map functioni](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798260/writing-my-own-generic-map-functioni)

Comment: You're adding requirements that you don't need, at least not in your example.  If you come up with a use case where you must have `<:<` instead of something else, fine, but show us that use case in the example.

Comment: @RexKerr I was using `<:<` because I couldn't get `<:` to work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472206/why-do-i-need-an-explicit-evidence-type-why-does-this-scala-type-bound-fail/8473044#8473044

Answer (score 4):

I've answered [this very question about type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390229/53013) just last week. Here's the code:

```
implicit def conv[A,C <: GenTraversable[A]](xs: C with GenTraversableLike[A,C]) = new {
  def mymap[B,D](f: A => B)(implicit b: CanBuildFrom[C,B,D]): D = {
    val builder = b(xs)
    xs foreach { x => builder += f(x) }
    builder.result
  }
}
```

I could have used `GenTraversable` instead of `GenTraversableLike` in this particular case. I prefer the later because it offers more.

The problem is that declaring `[A, C <: GenTraversable[A]]` **does not** instruct Scala to infer the type of `A` from the type of `C`. Types are inferred based on how they are used in the parameters, and then checked against the boundaries specified by the type parameters.

So when I write `xs: C with GenTraversable[A]`, I let Scala know it should infer `A` from `xs`. And writing `GenTraversableLike[A, C]` tells Scala it should pick a collection that *returns* `C` for methods that return the same collection. This means you can call `filter` and get `C` back, instead of getting `GenTraversable` back.

As for wishing to include views, that I don't know how you could accomplish.

Comment: Ugh, yet another rule to remember: use `with` to get around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472206. Could you explain why you constrain C to be both `GenTraversable[A]` and `GenTraversableLike[A,C]`? Why/when does `with` work but not `<:<` (and why not always use `with` instead of `<:`)? (A related question I have is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472134/why-does-this-scala-implicit-conversion-fail-when-explicit-conversion-works)? I'll mark your question as accepted but any explanation of the nuances here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Argh, your solution is no go: it doesn't work with `Array`s, since they in turn need an implicit conversion to become a collection, so `with` doesn't work here. In general this needs to handle any type that can be viewed as a collection, because I want things to behave as if I added a method to the collection hierarchy itself. Updated my question. Also, these are the types of issues I was hoping to catch by asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798260/writing-my-own-generic-map-functioni). You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-pimp-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections) where Rex Kerr explains how to perform such pimping in general.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: That one isn't pimpy. :)

Comment: I saw both threads already, and they don't answer my question. For instance, the type parameters I use here seem to match up with those in @missingfactor's other answer, but the implicit fails to work - feel free to tell me how to get it working. RexKerr's answer relies on C and D being type constructors (and while I can make C work as a type constructor, that's again broken, and D I can't make work at all as a type constructor).