# When to use `with` for bounding type parameters instead of `<:` or `<:<` in Scala?

Tags: scala

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472654/how-to-pimp-scala-collections-with-my-own-generic-map-the-right-way/8477943#8477943), I'm advised to use `with` in a place where one normally uses `<:` or `<:<`.  So instead of defining functions in either of the following two ways:

```
scala> def f[A,C <: Seq[A]](xs: C) = 0
f: [A, C <: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[A]](xs: C)Int

scala> f(List(1))
<console>:54: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,List[Int]] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A,C <: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[A]]
              f(List(1))
              ^

scala> implicit def f[A,C](xs: C)(implicit ev: C <:< Seq[A]) = new { def foo = 0 }
f: [A, C](xs: C)(implicit ev: <:<[C,scala.collection.immutable.Seq[A]])java.lang.Object{def foo: Int}

scala> List(0) foo
<console>:54: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< scala.collection.immutable.Seq[A].
              List(0) foo
                  ^

scala> f(List(0)) foo
res17: Int = 0
```

One can do:

```
scala> implicit def f[A,C](xs: C with Seq[A]) = new { def foo = 0 }
f: [A, C](xs: C with scala.collection.immutable.Seq[A])java.lang.Object{def foo: Int}

scala> List(0) foo
res18: Int = 0
```

My question is: besides the above particular case, when should one use `with` instead of `<:` or `<:<` on the type parameter?  Why not *always* use `with` instead?  I'm looking for a discussion of the nuances among the alternatives here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The meanings are entirely different. `C <: Seq[A]` means that `C` is a subtype of `Seq[A]`, as you know; `xs: C with Seq[A]` doesn't put any bound on `C`, but means that `xs` should be both a `C` and a `Seq[A]`. Therefore you should normally use the one you actually mean.

In `def f[A,C <: Seq[A]](xs: C)` the problem is that Scala's compiler can't infer `A` because it doesn't appear explicitly in the type of arguments. I don't see any reason in principle it *couldn't* infer `A`; it just doesn't currently. Replacing the type with `C with Seq[A]` means `A` now appears in the type of `xs` and allows the compiler to infer `A`. So if you really mean the bound, but `A` to be inferred, you actually need to write

```
implicit def f[A,C <: Seq[A]](xs: C with Seq[A])
```

instead of your third definition, and this is what the answer to the linked question does.

Comment: Huh? `C` *is* solved to be the most specific type, which - since we are constraining `C` to be a `Seq[A]` - means `C <: Seq[A]`, thus putting a bound on `C`.

Comment: No, you aren't constraining `C` at all. With your definition, you can call, e.g., `f[Int, Object](Seq[Int]())`.