# Basic type inferral

Tags: scala, types

Please consider `case class Foo[A, B <: List[A]](l: B) { ... }` or something akin. In particular, `A` as well as `B` need to be available somewhere in the body of `Foo`.

Is it possible for the compiler to infer `A` automatically? For example, `Foo(List(1,2,3))` fails as the type checker infers `A` as `Nothing`. Perhaps there is a way by using type members to solve this problem?

I have that certain feeling that I'm overlooking something embarassingly simple here ;)

EDIT: I just found out that using another type parameter `X` works just fine, but atm I don't understand why that is so:

```
scala> case class Bar[A, B[X] <: List[X]](l: B[A])
defined class Bar

scala> Bar(List(1,2,3))
res11: Bar[Int,List] = Bar(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Can someone please explain this to me? **Is this a unification issue?**

EDIT 2: Using `[A, B[X] <: List[X]](l: B[A])` can have undesired implications for certain hierarchies (although it's not really a big deal). More interestingly, I just stumbled across a [blog post](http://jsuereth.com/scala/2011/12/28/pluscolon-extractor.html) by Josh Suereth that implicitly shows that `[A, B <: List[A]](l: B with List[A])` works just as well... No need for implicits etc.

Comment: Can you define the class as `case class Foo[A](l: List[A])`? That might be more clear.

Comment: I understand what you mean but that's not applicable in my scenario. Both type A and B must be known apart from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481337/271678), in principle the type could be inferred automatically but simply isn't at the time being.

So, at least for now, all type parameters that should be inferred have to show up explicitly in the arguments.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really answer the "why" part, sorry, but here are some more tricks you can play. First, since you're not using the `X` in your example, you can write:

```
case class Bar[A,B[_] <: Seq[_]](l : B[A])
```

and then:

```
scala> Bar(List(1,2,3))
resN: Bar[Int,List] = Bar(List(1, 2, 3))
```

(I'm using the covariant `Seq` instead of `List` to show it works for subtypes as well. Also, note that this is not equivalent to using the extra `X`, see the comments.) Unfortunately, everytime you want to use the sequence type, you need to write `B[A]`, i.e. instantiate it manually. One way to work around that is to write instead:

```
case class Bar[A,B](l : B)(implicit ev : B <:< Seq[A])
```

In action:

```
scala> Bar(List(1,2,3))
resN: Bar[Int,List[Int]] = Bar(List(1, 2, 3))
```

...and you get the type parameters `A` and `B` instantiated just like you always knew they should.

Comment: This is bad advice.  Don't ever write "B[_] <: Seq[_]", it does not mean what you think it does.  He is indeed using the X, to link B's type parameter to Seq's.  The underscores in "B[_] <: Seq[_]" are not the same type.

Comment: Aside from the `_` problem, I found this in an interesting post as I never would have guessed that an implicit view could help. So where does the compiler find an implicit view for `B` as `Seq[A]`? When I tried in the console it found some function from Predef, but it also works with custom classes (apparently there's no possibility to have nicely formatted examples in this section, sorry). Is there a way to track which implicits the compiler pulls in?

Comment: Ah, ok, looking at the source of Predef reveals the "infrastructure" of <:<, =:=, and <%<.

Comment: Sorry, that first part wasn't so clear. They're indeed not equivalent, and `B[_] <: Seq[_]` is really `B[X] forSome { type X; } <: Seq[Y] forSome { type Y; }`. My point was, *in this case* it doesn't matter what the single `X` or the two existential `_`s get assigned to, because you never use them. For all you know `X` gets assigned to the pretty useless `Any`, and my two existentials to `Nothing` and `Any` respectively, but `B[A]` is what matters in the end.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible for the compiler to infer A automatically. But if it were possible it would have to say that A should be a *supertype* of Int, so Int or Any, not just Int!. Because a List[Int] <: List[Any]. So if the compiler would infer Int for A it would be too restrictive.

In other words:

1. `case class Foo[A, B <: List[A]](l: B) { ... }`
   and then calling it as `Foo(List(1,2,3))` you say that *A must be a type for which holds that a list of it should be a supertype of a list of Int*. 
   So effectively A must be a supertype of Int because List is covariant.
2. `case class Bar[A, B[X] <: List[X]](l: B[A])`
   and then calling it as `Foo(List(1,2,3))` you say that *A must be an Int*.

Case (2) leaves no room for A to be anything else than Int.
Case (1) however leaves room for A to be something else than Int, e.g. it could be Any.
You can see this because you could call it by `Foo[Any, List[Int]](List(1,2,3))`. You wouldn't be able to do this in case (2).

So the two cases are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, that `Foo[Any,List[Int]]` example is a good one. OTOH I'm wondering why, following your reasoning, it's still impossible to say something like `Foo[A, B >: List[A] <: List[A]]` because that would, from a logical point of view, remove the ambiguity (or wouldn't it, I wonder?). Yet in both cases, i.e. the latter as well as the one mentioned in my original post, the compiler infers `A` as `Nothing` and keeps complaining about that (understandable from my limited point of view) which is why I'm thinking that besides the covariance issue, this can also be explained in terms of unification?

Comment: Yes indeed, I follow your reasoning. I suppose this is what is meant with scala's type inferencing being incomplete.

Comment: There's this very nice [talk](http://screencasts.chariotsolutions.com/webpage/2011/10) from Daniel Spiewack about (not only Scala's) incomplete type inference. The intro is fairly long but the whole talk is very much worth it.

Comment: Appended some new "insight" to my original post, just in case you're interested.