# generic to specific collection after partial function application

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I am trying to apply a partial function to a generic collection while returning a specific collection instead of Traversable of the original type.

Here's what I've tried (among other things):

```
def filter[A, B, C <: Traversable[A],Y<:B, D <: Traversable[Y]](xs: Option[D] with TraversableLike[A,Option[D]])(pf:PartialFunction[A,B]): D = {
   xs.collect(pf)
}

def filter[A, B, C <: Traversable[A], D <: Traversable[B]](xs: D with TraversableLike[A,D])(pf:PartialFunction[A,B])(implicit ev: B =:= Option[Double]): D = {
   xs.collect(pf)
}
```

Any ideas why `implicit ev: B =:= Option[Double]` doesn't find the correct types?

I got inspiration from these posts:
[Returning original collection type in generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235462/returning-original-collection-type-in-generic-method/8390229#8390229)

[How do I apply the enrich-my-library pattern to Scala collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-enrich-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections)

[Writing my own generic map functioni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798260/writing-my-own-generic-map-functioni)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import scala.collection.Iterable
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def collect[C[_], A, B](col: C[A])
                       (pf: PartialFunction[A, B])
                      (implicit ev: C[A] <:< Iterable[A],
                                cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, B, C[B]]): C[B] =
  col.iterator.collect(pf).to[C]
```

Comment: @Adrian Yes you can, but **Trasversable** does not have `iterator`. Thus, the code will be mostly the same, but more inefficient _(specially if you chain multiple transformations)_ - Anyways, I doubt there is any collection type that is **Trasversable** but no **Iterable**.